# How to map two columns from two sheets and merge respective values in a new column in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have two tables in two sheets of MS Excel. Like:

Sheet 1 (15 columns):

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O                       
17  G-864   mtnD    R147-RXN    1.13.11.54  Klebsiella oxytoca  EV-EXP  Klebsiella oxytoca  acireductone dioxygenase [iron(II)-requiring]   PWY-7527    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.54  Bacillus 1.13.11.54 1                       
15  G-865   ARD1    R147-RXN    1.13.11.55  Oryza sativa    EV-EXP  Oryza sativa    1,2-dihydroxy-5-(methylthio)pent-1-en-3-one:oxygen oxidoreductase (formate-forming) PWY-7528    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.55  Bacillus 1.13.11.54 1                       
16  G-866   mtnD    R147-RXN    1.13.11.56  Klebsiella oxytoca  EV-EXP  Klebsiella oxytoca  acireductone dioxygenase [iron(II)-requiring]   PWY-7529    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.56  Bacillus 1.13.11.54 1                       
12  G-867   TYMS    R147-RXN    1.13.11.57  Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    thymidylate synthase    PWY-7530    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.57  Bacillus 2.1.1.45   1                       
14  G-868   MJ0757  R147-RXN    1.13.11.58  Methanocaldococcus jannaschii   EV-EXP  Methanocaldococcus jannaschii   thymidylate synthase    PWY-7531    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.58  Bacillus 2.1.1.45   1                       
13  G-869   thyA    R147-RXN    1.13.11.59  Mycobacterium tuberculosis H37Rv    EV-EXP  Mycobacterium tuberculosis  dTMP synthase   PWY-7532    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.59  Bacillus 2.1.1.45   1                       
1   G-870   dxs R147-RXN    1.13.11.60  Bacillus subtilis subtilis 168  EV-EXP  Bacillus subtilis   1-deoxyxylulose-5-phosphate synthase    PWY-7533    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.60  Bacillus 2.2.1.7    1
```

Sheet2 (5 columns):

```
Reprsentative_bacteria  IP_address  Reprsentative_bacteria IP_address   KO_ID_with_description  KO_ID                                       
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.11    Bacillus 1.13.11.54 K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase  K00850                                      
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.12    Bacillus 2.2.1.7    K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase  K02793                                      
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.13    Bacillus 2.1.1.45   K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase                                          
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.14    Lactobacillus 4.1.2.13  K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase  K01624                                      
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.15    Lactobacillus 5.3.1.1   K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase  K01803                                      
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.16    Lactobacillus 1.2.1.12  K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase  K00134                                      
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.17    Lactobacillus 2.7.2.3   K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase  K00927                                      
Lactobacillus   2.7.1.18    Lactobacillus 5.4.2.11  K00850 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11] | (GenBank) 6-phosphofructokinase  K01834
```

The 3rd column ( **Reprsentative_bacteria IP_address** ) of the 2nd sheet has unique values while the 14 th column ( **'N' column** ) of the 1st sheet has duplicate values.
Now, I want to take each value from the 3rd column of 2nd sheet and search that within the 14 th column of the 1st sheet. And, where matches, I want to make a separate column in the 1st sheet and enter the respective value from the 5th column (KO_ID) of the 2nd sheet. Finally, I want my 1st sheet to be look like:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   KO_ID
17  G-864   mtnD    R147-RXN    1.13.11.54  Klebsiella oxytoca  EV-EXP  Klebsiella oxytoca  acireductone dioxygenase [iron(II)-requiring]   PWY-7527    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.54  Bacillus 1.13.11.54 1   Bacillus 2.2.1.7
15  G-865   ARD1    R147-RXN    1.13.11.55  Oryza sativa    EV-EXP  Oryza sativa    1,2-dihydroxy-5-(methylthio)pent-1-en-3-one:oxygen oxidoreductase (formate-forming) PWY-7528    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.55  Bacillus 1.13.11.54 1   Bacillus 2.2.1.7
16  G-866   mtnD    R147-RXN    1.13.11.56  Klebsiella oxytoca  EV-EXP  Klebsiella oxytoca  acireductone dioxygenase [iron(II)-requiring]   PWY-7529    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.56  Bacillus 1.13.11.54 1   Bacillus 2.2.1.7
12  G-867   TYMS    R147-RXN    1.13.11.57  Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    thymidylate synthase    PWY-7530    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.57  Bacillus 2.1.1.45   1   
14  G-868   MJ0757  R147-RXN    1.13.11.58  Methanocaldococcus jannaschii   EV-EXP  Methanocaldococcus jannaschii   thymidylate synthase    PWY-7531    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.58  Bacillus 2.1.1.45   1   
13  G-869   thyA    R147-RXN    1.13.11.59  Mycobacterium tuberculosis H37Rv    EV-EXP  Mycobacterium tuberculosis  dTMP synthase   PWY-7532    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.59  Bacillus 2.1.1.45   1   
1   G-870   dxs R147-RXN    1.13.11.60  Bacillus subtilis subtilis 168  EV-EXP  Bacillus subtilis   1-deoxyxylulose-5-phosphate synthase    PWY-7533    Bacillus subtilis   Bacillus    1.13.11.60  Bacillus 2.2.1.7    1   Bacillus 2.2.1.7
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I get such result?

Many thanks

Comment: As I commented on your previous similar question:  Your tables have space between the fields. Since the data also contains space within the field, it is almost impossible to paste your data properly into a worksheet. Suggest you redo your presentation using a field separator that is NOT contained within the field (eg tab, pipe, etc) to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Ok Rosenfeld, I will definitely try to keep that in my mind from the next time

Comment: Let me know if you edit this question to change your data representation, and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a third sheet and started at the second row (only the data), I have put the following formulae:

```
on Column A : =Sheet1!A2
on Column B : =Sheet1!B2
on Column C : =Sheet1!C2
on Column D : =Sheet1!D2
on Column E : =Sheet1!E2
on Column F : =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!O2,Sheet2!C$2:F$9,4,FALSE)
```

As far as the `VLookup()` is concerned:

- Look for the value "Sheet1!O2"
- Look for that value in the matrix "Sheet2!C$2:F$9"
- Inside that matrix, look for the fourth column
- Don't to an approximate match, but an exact one (`FALSE`)

Remark: why `O2` and `C$2:F$9`?
It's the idea that you can drag your formula down. When you do that, the relative references (like `O2`) increase (to `O3`, `O4`, ...). However your search matrix should not change (hence absolute references: `C$2:F$9` always stays the same).

Comment: Thnaks Dominique for the answer. But, I don't understand what is the need of this part in your formulae:on `Column A : =Sheet1!A2
on Column B : =Sheet1!B2
on Column C : =Sheet1!C2
on Column D : =Sheet1!D2
on Column E : =Sheet1!E2`            what is the need to copy the A to E columns from the first sheet to a new sheet?